# Instrução Left Join em LINQ to entites

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, linq-to-sql

Tentei fazer um left join em LINQ da seguinte forma:

```
(from opr in db.Operacao
join vol in db.Volume on new { VOL_CODBAR = opr.OPR_CODBAR } equals new { VOL_CODBAR     = vol.VOL_CODBAR } into vol_join
from vol in vol_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {
  opr.OPR_IDX,
  opr.OPR_CODEMP,
  opr.OPR_CODFIL,
  opr.OPR_NUMVEI,
  opr.OPR_TIPOPR,
  vol.VOL_TITLE
})
```

Mas, em tempo de execução, e gerado a exceção:

> LINQ to Entities não reconhece o método 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ImprotecSistemas.PackLocator.PackServer.DataAccess.vwObtemFuncionario] DefaultIfEmpty[Operacao](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ImprotecSistemas.PackLocator.PackServer.DataAccess.Operacao])', que não pode ser convertido em uma expressão de armazenamento.

Segue abaixo, o que eu quero em SQL:

```
Select *
From operacao opr
     left join volumes vol on vol.VOL_CODBAR = OPR.OPR_CODBAR
```

Estou usando Entity Framework 3.5 C#

Comment: Você tentou assim, com o equals sem alias? Em vez de `new { VOL_CODBAR = opr.OPR_CODBAR } equals new { VOL_CODBAR     = vol.VOL_CODBAR }` apenas `opr.OPR_CODBAR equals vol.VOL_CODBAR`?

Comment: Sim. Eu já tentei dessa forma, e diversas outras, mas sempre da erro na função `DefaultIfEmpty()`. Para fazer um paliativo, criei um _subselect_, pois, no momento eu só preciso de uma coluna da segunda tabela. Mas, isso não é o correto.

Comment: pesquisei e descobri que de fato `DefaultIfEmpty()` não é suportado no `Entity Framework 3.5`.

Comment: Será que existe alguma alternativa para ele?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework 3.5 não tem LEFT JOIN para consultas com Linq. Mas há outra maneira de fazer isto, descrito aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5920182/2387977

Acredito que, no seu caso, o código deveria ser algo parecido com isto:

```
from opr in db.Operacao
select new 
{
  Operacao = opr,
  Volumes = opr.Volumes.Where(vol => vol.VOL_CODBAR = opr.OPR_CODBAR)
};
```